# How to find entry in registry of an uninstalled program?

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I want to know how one can find the entries in the registry of an uninstalled software. Can someone help me out because I have no idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you scan through the registry, some of the keys will point to files on the disk.  If these files do not exist, that is probably a key for uninstalled software.  Any key that references this key, is also probably for uninstalled software.

Comment: Very dangerous - a MRU list may very well contain files on removable storage (eg. USB stick, CD ROM). Don't assume you can edit MRU lists of random programs. For instance, Office uses key names "a", "b", "c" for its MRU lists. You can't just delete the "b" key because it refers to `H:\MySchoolPresentation.doc"

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The registry does not store the "source" or "use" of a registry key.

Comment: Blind luck and marketing. Check the warranty information on such products.

Comment: Or, in the case of good ones (such as CCleaner), a database of known applications, their keys, and an intelligent scan of the types which are related (mostly COM and MSI related)v